# MSDN Licensing?

Tags: windows-server-2008

Simple question, but one I can't find an answer to on the MSDN subscriber site: As an MSDN Professional Subscriber, can I install the same copy of Windows 2008 in multiple VMs at the same time?

The MSDN keys state that they can be used for "multiple activations", but they don't state whether these are sequential or concurrent. I seem to recall that Windows 2008 Enterprise has its own "you can run multiple instances in VMs" terms. Did I remember that right, and does that apply to MSDN subscriptions?

Comment: Kieron, this is very much programming related, as are most test environment and project deployment issues. Please don't retag n-p.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing not programming

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that each key is allotted 10 activations without regard to concurrence or sequence of the installations.  If the 10 activations are used up, Microsoft can be contacted to request additional keys.

A while back (I haven't checked recently), msdn subscribers also had access to an "online concierge" chat room, of sorts.  While the microsoft personnel who worked in that chat room couldn't answer technical questions (clearly, considering the breadth of technical questions that would be asked), they could answer real questions about msdn subscriptions and the licenses and rules associated with the software.  I asked them if I could use my MSDN license key to install a copy of an OS to work @home, per the agreement, e.g.

Comment: What's the answer from them about "install a copy of an OS to work @home"?

Answer (score 2):

If i recall correctly, you can run 10 activations of each one concurrently in a test environment and not a production environment.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - as long as you use them acording to msdn licence (developing, testing, presentation).

Your key will be valid for 10 activations, but you can ask for another key.